# Covariance matrix for p dimensional vector

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, covariance-matrix

I am working on making a conjecture about necessary and sufficient conditions for a singular covariance matrix of a p-dimensional random vector.

To get to this conjecture I have to find the conditions that the covariance matrix of a 2-dimensional random vector, $X=(X_1, X_2)^T$, is singular. Knowing that a matrix is singular if its determinant is 0, I said that the covariance matrix is singular iff $\sigma_{X_1}^2 \sigma_{X_2}^2 = \sigma_{X_1X_2}^2$. However, I am not sure how to generalize this to p-dimension.

Comment: Your formula doesn't look like a determinant.  Please tell us what you mean by the $\sigma^2_{X_i}.$ What exactly do you need to generalize, given that determinants are well-defined, understood, explained in many texts, and you have already articulated a correct criterion for singularity in any number of dimensions?

Comment: @whuber Thank you for pointing that out for me. I rewrote it.

Comment: Do you mean that $\sigma_{X_1X_2}$ is the covariance?  If so, then your equality is equivalent to the determinant being zero.

Comment: @whuber Finding the determinant of a p-dimensional matrix is very tedious. I was hoping there is a simpler way to get the conditions.

Comment: @whuber Yes, $\sigma_{X_1,X_2}$ is the covariance of $X_1, X_2$.

Comment: Okay.  What, then, would the generalization look like?  Are you looking for a formula for the determinant?  For alternative characterizations of singularity?  An efficient algorithm to check for singularity? (They exist: look up "row reduction".) Something else?

Comment: @whuber Either or.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I believe it could be about sample covariance matrix. The problem states that $X= (X_1, ..., X_p)$ is a random vector.

Comment: I guess dispersion matrix of $X$ is singular iff $a'X$ is a constant with probability $1$ for any non-zero vector $a$.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix $A$ is a covariance matrix if and only if it is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Which_matrices_are_covariance_matrices?)).

A symmetric matrix is positive definite if and only if all of its *leading principal minors* are strictly positive (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_symmetric_matrix#Other_characterizations)).

A symmetric matrix is positive semi-definite if and only if all of its *principal minors* are nonnegative (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion)).

I suppose you know what (leading) principal minors are. However, if $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, then (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra))):

- a *minor* is a square submatrix $A_{IJ}$ where $I$ and $J$ are subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$
- a *principal minor* is the determinant of $A_{IJ}$, $I=J$;
- a *leading principal minor* is the determinant of $A_{IJ}$ when $I=J=\{1\}$, or $I=J=\{1,2\}$, or $I=J=\{1,2,3\}$, etc.

You need a symmetric matrix which is positive semi-definite, but not positive definite: at least one $|A_{1,\dots,k;1;\dots,k}|$, i.e. at least one leading principal minor, must be null.

If $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, the easiest solution is $a_{11}=0$ (the first leading principal minor is null), i.e. if $X_1$ is a [degenerate random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution), then:
$$\begin{vmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a \end{vmatrix}=0$$
Another example is: $Z\sim N(0,1)$, $\mathbf{X}=(Z,-Z)$, because (see [here](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Edavar/math6010/2014/GaussianRandomVectors.pdf)):
$$\mathbf{\Sigma}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1, & 1 \end{bmatrix},\quad |\mathbf{\Sigma}|=0$$
i.e. the first leading principal minor is strictly positive, but the second one is null.

In general, degenerate multivariate distributions have singular covariance matrices. See [Does $(X,X)'$ follow a bivariate normal distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474045/does-x-x-follow-a-bivariate-normal-distribution).

Comment: Positive-definiteness is not equivalent to non-singular.

Comment: Right, because a non positive definite matrix may be non-singular: a negative definite matrix, which doesn't make sense as a variance matrix, is non-singular. But a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix which is not positive definite does make sense as a variance matrix and is singular. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's true: but you don't need to apply all of Sylvester's criteria to determine whether the matrix is singular.  There are simpler and more efficient solutions.  The most efficient I can think of is to triangulize the matrix using Gaussian reduction: as soon as a zero is found on the diagonal you can stop and declare the matrix singular, but if you complete the process with no zeros on the diagonal, the matrix is invertible.

Comment: But  as soon as a zero is found on the diagonal I can't stop and declare the matrix positive semi-definite. Singular is not equivalent to positive semi-definiteness, non-singular is not equivalent to positive definiteness :)

Comment: The question concerns determining whether a *covariance matrix* is singular.  Thus, no testing for positive semi-definiteness is needed.